# Access Swift public Var to objective c class

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift

I have following code in my `Appdelegate` class and want to access that in Objective C file for that I have already created Bridging file which works well for all methods.

```
public var loggedInUserModelObject = LoggedInUserModel(userDict:[String:Any]())
```

But when I try to access `loggedInUserModelObject` variable in objective C class it shows me This error.

[image]
I used `@objC` before the class and before the variable too but no success.
how can I access pubic variable in objective c file

Answer (score 8):

Are you using swift4?Rules of accessing variables have changed in swift 4.Instead of using @objc prefix in swift class use @objcMembers. This will expose all variables to objective c class. Example is given below.

**@objcMembers class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate**

If you want to expose single variable to swift class, use @objc before variable like the code shown below.

@objc public  var loggedInUserModelObject : NSString?